# Periodicity (Fibonacci mod sequence) in infinites list Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to create a function in Haskell, which works as follows

```
periodicity ::[Integer] ->[Integer]
periodicity [1,2,3,3,4,1,2,3,3,4...] = [1,2,3,4]
periodicity [0,1,2,2,5,4,3,3,0,1,2,5,4...] = [0,1,2,5,4,3]
```

That is to say, that from a list you get the part that is always repeated, what in Mathematical Sciences would be called period of a function.

I've tried this, but I doesn't work like I want for the reason that I want that work with infinites list

```
periodicty :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
periodicity xs = take n xs
    where l = length xs
          n = head [m | m <- divisors l, 
                        concat (replicate (l `div` m) (take m xs)) == xs]
```

I have found this function that gives me the length of period, I could have solved the problem, but I don't understand the code after where:

```
periodo 1 = 1
periodo n = f 1 ps 0
  where
   f 0 (1 : xs) pi = pi
   f _ (x : xs) pi = f x xs (pi + 1)
   ps = 1 : 1 : zipWith (\u v -> (u + v) `mod` n) (tail ps) ps
```

Comment: How would one ever decide that an arbitrary infinite list *never* breaks the pattern, after the finite part of it we were able to check in finite time?

Comment: Well, if the same pattern is repeated three times, we already know (or I know enough to know) that it is periodic.  @Davislor

Comment: @mathandtic: but if the list is `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 3, 4]`, then the pattern was repeated three times, but not an inifinite amount of tims.

Comment: This would work if I piped in `map (fromIntegral . fromEnum) <$> getContents` and adversarially tried to break the algorithm?

Comment: What I really want is a function that gets a periodic part of the Fibonacci module n succession. But, I have thought that it is better to do `periodicity` and then apply `map' to that list.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period   @Davislor

Comment: In that special case, any sequence of length 2 or greater that repeats itself even once is guaranteed to repeat infinitely. (I think; it’s after midnight.)

Comment: I think so, but I'm not able to write the correct code

Comment: Or any single value (mod `n`) that repeats 3 times is guaranteed to repeat forever.

Comment: Yes, but if for example it is `mod 17` the period size will be bigger than `mod 3`, how can I create the function that gives me the period list for $\forall$ n

Comment: As for that `periodo` function, `ps` is just the fibonacci sequence mod n.  `f` is a recursive function that walks through the list.  `pi` keeps track of the current index.  Can you figure out the rest?

Comment: I could do it more or less

Comment: `(\u v -> (u + v) `mod` n) ` can I write ussing `map`?

Comment: @mathandtic I assume you mean the whole ``zipWith (\u v -> (u + v) `mod` n) (tail ps) ps`` bit.  No, you can't write it using `map`, unless you *also* `zip`, because you need to combine two lists.

Comment: In one special case (*m* = 5 is one example), you can determine that the period is 2 *i* after checking *i* + 1 elements, and you can classify this special case using the first *m* ²/2+1 elements. The check takes only constant memory. See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you want, as you have stated it, is impossible<sup>1</sup>.

But since you said you are really after is the Pisano period, it's enough to notice that two successive numbers is enough to determine the remainder of a fibonacci sequence (mod n or otherwise).  So you are really looking for the first reoccurrence of an adjacent pair, e.g.

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0
^^^^                    ^^^^
[--------- 8 -----------)
```

I am not much for coding people's problems for them, but I can sketch the way I would solve this.  One thing to keep in mind is that the periodicity might have a prefix that does not repeat -- I don't know whether this actually occurs in Fibonacci sequences mod n, but it occurs in general.  So we need to be prepared to throw away a prefix.

First, `zip` the list with its tail to get a list of adjacent pairs

```
    [ 0,     1,     1,     2,     0,     2,    2,     1 ...]
 -> [(0,1), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (0,2), (2,2), (2,1), ... ]
```

From this, fold through the list building a `Data.Map` keyed on this pair, where the value is the index it first occurred.  You could do this with `foldr` but I'd probably just use a recursive function with an accumulator.   For the above example the map at each step would look like:

```
{(0,1): 0}
{(0,1): 0, (1,1): 1}
{(0,1): 0, (1,1): 1, (1,2): 2}
{(0,1): 0, (1,1): 1, (1,2): 2, (2,0): 3}
...
```

When you reach a point in the list where the key is already present, you can then subtract the current index from the one in the map, and there's your period.

---

<sup>1</sup> Here's a proof.  Let's say you have the specification for a Turing machine, and you make a list `steps` of the steps of its execution.  This list will be finite if it halts, infinite otherwise.  Now construct this list:

```
bad = zipWith const (cycle [1,2,3]) steps ++ cycle [1,2,3,4]
```

This list cycles with period 3 as long as the machine runs, and with period 4 afterward.  So if the Turing machine halts, `periodicity bad = 4`, otherwise `periodicity bad = 3`.  That is, `periodicity` can decide the halting problem, which is impossible.

Comment: Nice reduction to the halting problem!

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is impossible for an arbitrary infinite list.  We can only examine a finite sublist in finite time, and the next element of the list might, for all we know, break the pattern.

In your comments, you clarify that you really are looking for a periodic part of the Fibonacci sequence, modulo *m*.  In that special case, it is possible, if I understand you correctly.

The Fibonacci sequence (mod *m*) is periodic after a certain point if either the same value repeats three times: the previous two values are both equal to their predecessors, so the function becomes periodic with a period of 1.  It is also periodic after a certain point if any sequence of two or more numbers repeats even once, as then we know that the this value and its predecessor are repeats of the ones *k* and *k*-1 terms ago, and the function will generate the same subsequence again with period *k*.  There is no shorter period, or we would have detected it, going left to right.

Furthermore, any sequence that repeats infinitely will repeat once first, so this detects all such sequences.

Therefore, a better way to calculate this than I originally wrote would be to search for the current number and its predecessor earlier in the list.  (You can use luqui’s strategy of building a list of consecutive pairs, or search the same data structure recursively instead of building a new one.)  If a match exists, the sequence is guaranteed to repeat with a period equal to the distance between the two appearances of the same pair.

That takes time quadratic in the length of the non-periodic initial subsequence, since you search each initial subsequence from the beginning.  To do it in linear time with an upper bound of *m* ²+2 steps: we know there are only *m* possible values, meaning only *m* ² possible pairs of values, a sequence of *k* numbers contains *k*-1 consecutive pairs of numbers, and therefore by the pigeonhole principle the first *m* ²+2 elements of the sequence must contain some pair of consecutive values in two different places, and become periodic from the first instance of the pair onward. So searching that fixed-length initial subsequence suffices, and we can build a table of the index (if any) of each of the *n* ² potential pairs in the list until we encounter the first duplicate.  (That said, we would need to use a mutable array, so we sacrifice either speed or functional purity.)

This is similar to lugui’s algorithm, but with a faster lookup.

#### Conjecture

The sequence is periodic iff `0:1` appears more than once. If every Fibonacci sequence (mod *m*) is periodic, then the period is simply the position of the second occurrence of `[0,1]`.

`0:1` would be generated only by a preceding `-1:1`, which would be generated by a preceding `-3:2`, which would be generated by a preceding `-8:5`, and so on.  [...,-8,5,-3,2,-1,1,0] is exactly the fibonacci sequence, backwards, with alternating sign, mod *m*, and if any two consecutive numbers appear in the original sequence, it is periodic.  Thus, iff [0,1,1] would ever be generated by this pattern, it will eventually generate `0:1` in the Fibonacci sequence mod *m*.  This occurs iff *m*-1 and 1 occur consecutively in Fibo mod *m*, in either order.

#### Two Special Cases

If Fibo mod *m* contains `m-1:1` at position *i*, the sequence has period *i*+2, and if it contains `1:m-1`, the sequence has period 2 *i*+4. (If the sequence contains `1:-1`, the next position is *i*+2 and the next *i*+2 steps are: {0,-1,-1,-2,-3,-5,...,-1,1}). So this lets us shortcut a bit; when we see `1,4` at position 8 of Fibo mod 5, we know the sequence has a period of 20. In this special case, the scan needs fewer than half the elements on average, has an upper bound of *m* ²/2+1 elements to scan in order to rule the case out, and uses constant memory.